# Convert kilobytes in degrees

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to program a speedometer! I have a needle image, and I want the needle to rotate according to the current download speed.

I have the following method, but it is not working. When i update my needle with CurrentDegress, it never goes down, only higher and higher; the needle rotates around the circle...Anyone?!

```
- (void) recalculateDegrees:(CGFloat) currentlyLoadedBytes
{
    if(bytes <= 0){
        currentDegrees = 0;
    }
    else if (bytes > completeFileSize){
        currentDegrees = MAX_DEGREES;
    }
    else {
        CGFloat log_tmp =(CGFloat) log10f(currentlyLoadedBytes / 1000);
        currentDegrees = (log_tmp/5.0f)*290.0f;
    }
    //code to rotate image to currentDegrees
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for some basic trigonometric answer or for how to compute the sinus and cosinus of an angle ?

Comment: Is this meter supposed to indicate rate of download, or percent complete?

Comment: No, i am looking for the right calculation for my moving needle....:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to get the angle from the speed value (and not from `currentlyLoadedBytes`):

```
- (CGFloat)angleFromSpeed:(CGFloat)speed
{
    if (speed <= 0) {
        return MIN_ANGLE;
    } else if (speed >= MAX_SPEED) {
        return MAX_ANGLE;
    } else {
        return speed / MAX_SPEED * (MAX_ANGLE - MIN_ANGLE) + MIN_ANGLE;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi, i don´t get this...can you explain it a bit more please...:)

Comment: awwwwww sweet, it works....Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow 100% of what you are doing, but somewhere in your `else` block you should be dividing `currentlyLoadedBytes / completeFileSize`. Also, is `bytes` supposed to be `cuurentlyLoadedBytes`?

Comment: oh yee, sorry bytes should be currentlyLoadedBytes

Comment: i want to make a speedtest! i already calculate the right speed, but now i want that my needle rotates to the right position on my graph!

Comment: I calculate the Speed just with:    speed = currentFileSize / ([NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - startTime);